# Foreach on controls not working

Tags: asp.net, foreach, textbox, autopostback

I have this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox && c != null)
                ((TextBox)c).AutoPostBack = true;
        }
}
```

And alot of:

```
 protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

which dont trigger, I think that the problem is that the foreach doesnt set the autopostbacks of the textboxes to true, but I dont know why!

Answer (score 0):

As i remember you can not modify objects into foreach loop, try with for

```
    for (int x = 0; x < this.Controls.GetLength(); x++)
    {
        if (this.Controls[x] is TextBox && this.Controls[x] != null)
            ((TextBox)this.Controls[x]).AutoPostBack = true;
    }
```

Comment: Updated, try again. Long time ago since last time i code with c#

Comment: Its still not working :( I have also tried .count which doesnt work as well